# custom attributes on custom html tags in angular 2

Tags: html, angular

I've built a component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-g-switch',
  template: `
    <div id="switch" (click)='toggle()' [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url('+photo+')'}"></div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./g-switch.component.scss']
})
export class GSwitchComponent implements OnInit {

  _value: number;
  photo = '../../assets/sw-1-1.png';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // this._value = 1;
  }

  public returnValue(): number {
    return this._value;
  }

  toggle() {
    this._value++;
    if (this._value === 4) {
      this._value = 1;
    }
    this.photo = '../../assets/sw-1-' + this._value + '.png';
  }

}
```

which I include in my template with

```
<app-g-switch #sw1></app-g-switch>
```

I'd like to be able to pass value to the component, which I've seen done before like this,

```
<app-g-switch #sw1 [value]="2"></app-g-switch>
```

How can this be achieved? I tried to implement a setter but it didn't work.

Comment: You should check out the docs: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#inputs-outputs, Read the Input section

Comment: yes - valuable source of information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Angular documentation has a sub-section under their *Template and Data Binding* documentation which describes the `@Input` and `@Output` template syntax that you're looking for.

See Angular's documentation on [*Input and output properties*](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#inputs-outputs).

---

#### Example

In your scenario, you want to be able to initialize the `_value` variable from an HTML directive on your components selector.

Mark `_value` with the @Input decorator to declare it as an input directive field.

```
@Input
_value: number;
```

Now, you can set the `_value` parameter from your component selector, as follows,

```
<app-g-switch [_value]="1"> </app-g-switch>
```

Comment: If you feel my answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't

Comment: didn't knew this.. did it now :)

Comment: The `@Input` and `@Output` decorators are for use on a Component Selector only. Look into other directives if you're trying to accomplish something similar with default HTML elements.